# Listbox and combobox databinding in silverlight

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I am trying to implement and learn Silverlight Databinding using lab giving http://www.silverlight.net/learn/data-networking/binding/silverlight-data-binding. I do everything as soon in the lab but some how, I am not able to filter item into Listbox, even though, I am able to see item in listbox. Also, when I select any item in list box it doesn't show up text in textbox using public class for binding but when I do Element binding with Listbox then it do display the text in textbox.

I double check the code giving in lab everything looks similar but I am not able to get Databinding working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Your DataContext Is proper. Check Means it may be possible spelling mistake. otherwise it is difficult to say what's the mistake in your code without see it.